# Generating dynamic form fields from querysets in Django

Tags: django, forms

So I have this queryset that I get by using a filter.

The queryset looks like this:

```
<QuerySet [<Producto: Budin>, <Producto: Papas>, <Producto: Bolson de verduras>, <Producto: Bolson frutal>, <Producto: Pepas>, <Producto: Popas>, <Producto: Pipos>, <Producto: Café Molido Colombiano Agroecólogico Pues x1/2Kg>, <Producto: Albacores>, <Producto: Cangrejos>, <Producto: Peces>, <Producto: lardis>, <Producto: nueces>]>
```

The filter looks like this:

```
Producto.objects.filter(productor=pk)
```

Each "producto" from the queryset has a field called stock. I want to generate dynamic forms that display, for each user, the amount of stock they have and a form field for they to change it

It should look like this: https://gyazo.com/e1a1024515ff31e1f6d00e35a0f464fb

How should the forms.py class look like?

Comment: So what you are saying is that you would like to know to to set initial values for your form fields?

Comment: no (that's just a detail). what i want to do is to set dynamic form fields. So i don't want to specify the form field name. For the queryset above, I would need a form field "Budin", another "papas", etc...

Comment: The whole point of this is to let people modify the queryset objects properties. So Budin has an attribute called "stock" (as in, how much of it there is). the owner of the object "budin" should determine the stock value.

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](https://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/)?

Comment: nice find, i will try it out